# CLI tools when using bash on windows with subsystem for Linux

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed NPM for Windows, Git for Windows and bunch for global NPM packages that I can use from command line.

When I use bash shell from Windows Subsystem for Linux, do I have to install all the tools again in the Linux subsystem?

Answer (score 1):

No!

But **you will need to set up your WSL environment to conveniently access Windows programs**.

See below, How

- In your WSL .profile, set PATH to include the directories where your Windows programs are installed
- set WHOME to your Windows home directory where many files go by default.

Note, append ".exe" to command name. Some Windows commands will accept "-option" style arguments, but you might have to use "/option".

Finally,
You can use "wslpath" command to convert between Windows file names using "C:" and WSL file names using "/mnt/c".

Comment: Cygwin does not require appending ".exe" to command names. Cygwin uses the environment variable:

Comment: The PATH environment is brought in automatically from windows (since beta).  I also have never heard of WHOME and can find no reference to it within MS docs (old or new).

Comment: WHOME is an environment variable which I use (see http://ContextKnowledge.Blog) for Windows 10 multi-OS environment.

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin does not require appending ".exe" to command names. Cygwin uses the environment variable:
declare -x PATHEXT=".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC"

I assume the system exec() function was modified to search suffixes.

Comment: This question is not about what Cygwin does or doesn't do.  It is about what WSL does.  WSL needs the .exe to differentiate between PE and ELF binaries and run them in the appropriate sub-system.